# DefaultAzureCredential exception with multiple accounts in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, identity

I ran into the following scenario and eventually figured out the issue:

I have an ASP.NET application that has a runtime dependency on an Azure Key Vault, via a AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder. Running from my local machine using Visual Studio 2019, it is able to access the Key Vault if only my work (@microsoft.com) account is added to Visual Studio. However, if I have both my personal Microsoft account (@live.com) and my work account (@microsoft.com) added to Visual Studio, the application attempts to authenticate against the Key Vault using my personal Microsoft account (@live.com), when it should be using the work (@microsoft.com) account.

With both accounts logged into Visual Studio, I receive the following exception:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The configBuilder 'AzureKeyVault' failed while processing the configuration section 'appSettings'.: Error in Configuration Builder 'AzureKeyVault'::GetValue(AzureStorageConnectionString)

Source Error:


Line 32:     </builders>
Line 33:   </configBuilders>
Line 34:    <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
Line 35:        <add key="AzureStorageConnectionString" value="" />
Line 36:    </appSettings>

Source File: C:\<path to ASP.NET Web project>\web.config    Line: 34


Click here to show additional error information:

Exception Details: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple accounts were found in the cache. Use username and tenant id to disambiguate.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went through a lot of trial-and-error, setting credentials at the Environment variable level, Visual Studio level, and the Azure CLI level, but none of these were being respected when multiple accounts were registered in Visual Studio.

The issue was with the Azure.Identity package that is used to authenticate ASP.NET applications against Azure for development environments. I had version 1.1.1 of the package installed. Multiple issues with concurrent calls to DefaultAzureCredential [have been fixed in versions 1.2.0 and 1.3.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Identity_1.3.0/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/CHANGELOG.md). As such, updating to version 1.3.0 solved my issue and properly respected [the setting of the VisualStudioCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#authenticating-via-visual-studio).

DefaultAzureCredential [specifies a control flow](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#defaultazurecredential) of fetching different authentication tokens from various sources.

Comment: Such a spot-on response! I had the same error trying to debug my Durable Function and found that [it does indeed reference Azure.Identity 1.1.1 by default](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/2.6.1?_src=template), even though that package is already at version 1.6.0!. After installing `Azure.Identity` 1.6.0 explicitly I got another, much more specific error that points to a problem in our AAD configuration.

Comment: @julealgon glad it was of some help to you!